# Binomial distribution

Tags: probability

). May be this is so easy but i m not getting how to do that.
My question is..
In a party, 15 people were asked to select a number from 1 to 10, randomly. What is the probability 0f 3 out of 15 are choosing number 7. If we want to solve it using binomial then we have all the information required like n=15, p= 1/10, q= 9/10. Using this we can find P(3). What if I don't want to use binomial distribution. How can I solve this question then?

The way which I was trying is ...

Success,Failure,Number of cases

---

0, 15,1

---

1,14,15

---

2,  13, 105

---

3,  12, 455

---

4,  11, 1365

---

5,  10, 3003

---

6,  9,  5005

---

7,  8,  6435

---

8,  7,  6435

---

9,  6,  5005

---

10, 5,  3003

---

11, 4,  1365

---

12, 3,  455

---

13, 2,  105

---

14, 1,  15

---

15, 0,  1

---

```
    total number of cases= 32768
```

According to me p(3)= 455*(1/ 32768)

But this answer is totally different from the answer, using binomial formula. 
I don't know where I am wrong. Plz help me :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of $455$ is correct. However, "success" and "failure" are **not equally likely**. Dividing $455$ by $2^{15}$ essentially assumes that we are tossing a fair coin.

For example, the calculation assumes that $3$ successes and $12$ failures is just as likely as $12$ successes and $3$ failures. But it is clear that $12$ people choosing $7$ is extremely unlikely, while $3$ people choosing $7$ is not rare.

**Added** Record the choices of the $15$ people as a string of length $15$, made up of the "letters" $1$ to $10$. There are $10^{15}$ such strings, and they **are** all equally likely. We count the number of strings that have exactly $3$ $7$'s. The **location** of the $7$'s can be chosen in $\binom{15}{3}$ ways. Once we have done this, we have to fill the remaining $12$ slots with non-$7$'s. This can be done in $9^{12}$ ways. So our probability is
$$\frac{\binom{15}{3}9^{12}}{10^{15}}.$$
Alternately and almost equivalently, the number of successes has *Binomial Distribution*. The probability of exactly $3$ successes is $\binom{15}{3}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^3\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{12}$.

Comment: @Nicolas . Oh yes I didn't think in that way. They are not at all equally likely. But the same question again. what do I do now?

Comment: @Sh_sharma: I thought the post indicated that you knew: we use the binomial distribution. The probability that the number of successes is $3$ is $\binom{15}{3}(1/10)^3(9/10)^{12}$. One can give a more combinatorial analysis, I think I will add it.

Comment: @Nicolas .. I know Binomial distribution but what I am asking is I don't want to use Binomial distribution. Is there any other way? 
Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: Nicolas . Oh i am sorry I didn't see what u have added . Now its clear to me.. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: One can avoid explicit mention of binomial coefficients by using permutations instead, or by using generating functions. In my added material, I did not use the Binomial distribution, I used counting. But all these ideas are close to each other. Your proposal that led to the wrong answer used a whole lot of binomial coefficients, in particular $\binom{15}{3}=455$.

Comment: @Nicolas: I think I am getting the whole idea behind this problem. And i will see the other methods too and will try to relate them. Probability seems interesting :). Thank you so much Andre :-)